# Ubuntu won't shutdown (system halted)

Tags: shutdown, 14.10, acpi

I have an Acer Aspire E1 (ES1-311-P1D5) and I installed Ubuntu 14.10 on it. SecureBoot is enabled.

When I try to shutdown the system, it will stop but won't shutdown the computer itself. I've read that this is an ACPI issue, so I tried the kernel parameters 'acpi=off' and 'acpi=force'. It didn't work.

What else can I do now?

Comment: are you have shutdown via terminal (i mean cli mode by press ctrl+alt+F1) and next type shutdown -h now

Comment: This is due to problem realted to system updates they were not installed correctly or may have halted and `sudo shutdown` is a way to kill it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by updating my BIOS. Last time I checked there wasn't any update.